# How does a multi-input LSTM fail to learn, if even a Fully-Connected Network, that only operates on the prefix works?

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm struggling to understand how a simpler model can beat the more sophisticated model on the following problem:

I got two time-series (think random-walks for a semi-supervised setting) and want to do binary-classification to decide if they are "similar".
Here are two examples (first with positive label, second with negative label):
[image]

[image]

I implemented a model, that encodes both sequences and than passes both into a fully-connected layer:

```
input_1 = keras.Input(shape=(None, 1))
input_2 = keras.Input(shape=(None, 1))
shared_lstm = layers.LSTM(100)
encode_1 = shared_lstm(input_1)
encode_2 = shared_lstm(input_2)
concat = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([encode_1, encode_2])
hidden = layers.Dense(50, activation='sigmoid')(concat)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden)
m = keras.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
m.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

which does not learn at all (~50% accuracy).

Alternatively (only taking in the first 30 datapoints of each sequence):

```
m = Sequential()
m.add(Dense(200, input_dim=60, activation='relu'))
m.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
m.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
m.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

contains less parameters but easily reaches 95+% val-accuracy as least on my current dataset.

Can someone point be to what I am doing wrong?

Let me know if you need to see the dataset processing/generation.

Comment: The first 30 points of each sequence can very easily be considered similar, especially if the sequences are long. Of course, simpler models can outperform more complex ones, but i think the case here is what percent of the whole sequence do the 30 points represent. One model is trained on whole sequence (so smaller probability 2 will match on each point), other on only a small percent (thus larger prob that they can match). I think this is what happens

Comment: Don't you think the lstm model is wrong, then? I mean the accuracy is not changing at all.

Comment: Try using more points in simpler model and compare

Comment: Or use less points in LSTM and compare. This procedure should settle some questions regarding the two routes followed

Comment: I am not sure of the use/applicability of a shared layer in this case. You should zip both the seq and treat it as two featured seq. Keep a simple LSTM layer.